# permuting a 3-d array with mpi datatypes

Tags: mpi

Let's say you have a 3d array A[I][J][K], but you want to permute it into B[J][K][I].

This problem is similar to, but different from, the 2-d array transpose problem discussed here:
[Can you transpose array when sending using MPI_Type_create_subarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626123/can-you-transpose-array-when-sending-using-mpi-type-create-subarray).

The MPI standard provides examples of multi-dimensional array operations with user-defined datatypes, but not this particular case: http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-11-html/node61.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is with `MPI_TYPE_VECTOR` and `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_HVECTOR`, but the devil is in the details.

```c
/* data[I][J][K] is I by J by K (stored in array 'dim_sizes[] = {I, J, K}'
   and we want permuted[J][K][I] */

/* new innermost dimension is I items, strided across the old JK face*/
MPI_Type_vector(dim_sizes[0], 1, dim_sizes[1]*dim_sizes[2], 
    MPI_DOUBLE, &one_d);
MPI_Type_commit(&one_d);

/* new middle dimenson is K items, strided over the K row, which isn't
 * actually a stride in this case.  We use hvector here because we 
 * operate directly in terms of array items */
MPI_Type_create_hvector(dim_sizes[2], 1, sizeof(double), one_d, &two_d);
MPI_Type_commit(&two_d);

/* new outermost dimension is J items, strided over the old J row */
MPI_Type_create_hvector(dim_sizes[1], 1, dim_sizes[2]*sizeof(double), two_d,
    &transposed_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&transposed_type);
```

Now you can feed `transposed_type` to your send/receive call or make it your MPI file view.

Comment: You have to call `MPI_Type_commit` for each datatype that was created. `MPI_Type_hvector` is long deprecated - one should use `MPI_Type_create_hvector` instead. I've edited your answer accordingly.

Comment: good catch on the type_commit. My personal preference is to commit the final type and not the constituent types, since one_d and two_d will never be used in a send/receive or file_set_view call.  Thank you also for updating the deprecated type_hvector call.

Comment: You're absolutely right - there is no need to commit types which are not used in communication calls, but it makes a good programming practice to do so, since later one might decide to use one of the intermediate types.