# MPI matrix transpose

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

Hello everyone i am trying to do matrix transpose but i am complete newbie please help me to complete the matrix transpose:
Please suggest me if there is any source on internet for learning about mpi.
Should i start parallel programming first?
Please solve the below blank code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
int rank,size,m[4];
int matrix[4][4]={
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12},
    {13,14,15,16}
}
int transpose[4][4];

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

if (rank==0)
{
//Store first row of the matrix.
}
if(size!=4)
{
 exit(0);
}
else
{

}

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solving matrix transpose with no knowledge in MPI is indeed difficult. If you know the basic concepts, then it is very easy to solve. As a starting point, you can visit the [website](https://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/) for MPI lessons.

As a first step, get familiarised with the point to point communication mechanisms and try to use `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` to solve some simple tasks as pointed out in comments by **High Performance Mark**.

Secondly, move on to collective operations like `MPI_Scatter`, `MPI_Gather` etc to do the same tasks.

Then you will familiarise with the basic concepts and with this knowledge you can tackle your task.

This solution [1](https://userinfo.surfsara.nl/sites/default/files/second_0.c), [2](https://www.msi.umn.edu/workshops/mpi/hands-on/data-movement/alltoall/c) solves matrix transpose using `MPI_Alltoall` routine (as mentioned in comment by **Gilles Gouaillardet**).

Answer (score 0):

You can see the references here:
1. [Can you transpose array when sending using MPI_Type_create_subarray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626123/can-you-transpose-array-when-sending-using-mpi-type-create-subarray)
2. http://suraj.lums.edu.pk/~ahmadh/resources/code/matrixtransp.c
3. https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hwloidl/Courses/F21DP/srcs/matrix4.c

But first I thing you should try with simple examples like parallel some for loop for calculation like sum or multi.

Comment: These examples are unnecessarily convoluted imho. `MPI_Scatter(); MPI_Alltoall(); MPI_Gather()` is a very simple way to perform the transposition (and learn MPI too).